# Clear CheckBoxes in Specific Columns

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to clear all checkboxes in two specific columns (roughly 40 checkboxes in each column).  Here's what I have:

```
Worksheets("Roster").Column(5).CheckBoxes.Value = False
Worksheets("Roster").Column(7).CheckBoxes.Value = False
```

I also tried this:

```
ActiveSheet.Column(5).CheckBoxes.Value = False
ActiveSheet.Column(7).CheckBoxes.Value = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CheckBoxes aren't members of a Column.

If they are form-controls then they belong to a worksheet's `CheckBoxes` collection. If ActiveX controls they belong to the sheet's `OLEObjects` collection, but can also be accessed via the sheet's `Shapes` collection.

In either case you would reference them by either their index number (CheckBoxes(1), OLEObjects(1)) or their name.

---

If they are **form-controls** then you can find those that are linked (LinkedCell) to a particular column using this code:

```
Dim ckb As Object
Dim sLinked As String

For Each ckb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    sLinked = ckb.LinkedCell
    If sLinked <> "" Then
        '.. there is a LinkedCell
        If Range(sLinked).Column = 5 Or Range(sLinked).Column = 7 Then
            Debug.Print "found one.."
            Range(sLinked).Value = False
        End If
    End If
Next ckb
```

Notice that this changes the value in the linked-cell, not the control itself.

It should be possible to do something similar with ActiveX controls.

Comment: Well that explains why it doesn't work.  Is there a way to select every checkbox in column 5?  - Never mind...that doesn't make sense

Comment: You haven't yet stated what kind of controls they are, but I've added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I ended with this:

    `For i = 2 To 39`
    `Worksheets("Roster").Range("E" & i).Value = False`
    `Worksheets("Roster").Range("G" & i).Value = False`
    `Next i`

Comment: Erm, if you know the specific range then you can just do `Range("E2:E39,G2:G39").Value = False`.